# C# Linq query help removing foreach loops creating cleaner code

Tags: c#, linq

Is there a way to remove the for loops using linq to solve the problem I have

I want to get the subject and sum of points for each student and each subject in this list:

```
IEnumerable<Student> students = new List<Student> {
    new Student() {Id = 1, Name = "John", Age = 13},
    new Student() {Id = 2, Name = "Mary", Age = 12},
    new Student() {Id = 3, Name = "Anne", Age = 14}
};
```

I have a second list containing all the scores and subject information:

```
IEnumerable<StudentScore> studentScores = new List<StudentScore> {
    new StudentScore() {StudentId = 1, Subject = "Maths", Points = 54},
    new StudentScore() {StudentId = 1, Subject = "Maths", Points = 32},
    new StudentScore() {StudentId = 1, Subject = "English", Points = 55},
    new StudentScore() {StudentId = 1, Subject = "English", Points = 54},

    new StudentScore() {StudentId = 2, Subject = "Maths", Points = 44},
    new StudentScore() {StudentId = 2, Subject = "Maths", Points = 37},
    new StudentScore() {StudentId = 2, Subject = "English", Points = 59},
    new StudentScore() {StudentId = 2, Subject = "English", Points = 64},

    new StudentScore() {StudentId = 3, Subject = "Maths", Points = 53},
    new StudentScore() {StudentId = 3, Subject = "Maths", Points = 72},
    new StudentScore() {StudentId = 3, Subject = "English", Points = 54},
    new StudentScore() {StudentId = 3, Subject = "English", Points = 59},
};
```

this is the solution I came up with:

```
foreach (var student in students)
{
    foreach (var studentScore in studentScores.Select(ss=>ss.Subject).Distinct())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Name: " + student.Name + " Subject:" + studentScore + "Score: " + studentScores.Where(ss => ss.StudentId == student.Id)
                                                                               .Where(ss => ss.Subject == studentScore)
                                                                               .Sum(ss => ss.Points));
    }
}
```

Comment: I've never really bought into the opinion that Linq vs loops makes for cleaner code.  I can recognize a loop while "skimming" code pretty easily... with Linq I need to actually read the code to see what's going on.  It's a matter of syntactic sugar and usually I find there's more important things to focus on.  Take the answer from Brett below: harder to read than your original for loops!

Comment: @jdl134679 Are you talking about LINQ methods (`.Where(x=>x.StudentID=5)`) or about LINQ keyword syntax? Personally, I feel that the keyword syntax is slightly unnatural and doesn't make my code more concise; whereas using LINQ methods can condense the 3-5 lines of nested `foreach` logic into a single method call.

Comment: I guess generally speaking I use linq methods for selecting data, but actual for/foreach blocks for operating on data.  It's things like `col.Each((x) => x.This = That);` that I tend to avoid - the traditional for/foreach block structure stands out in code and is easily recognized as "an operation" against some set of objects. (to be fair, my complaint wasn't directly inline with OPs question, more of a side rant)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution has both a belt and suspenders - the `foreach` loops are combined with LINQ, where LINQ part is dependent on the values through which you go in your `foreach` loop.

The trick to understanding how this could be done entirely with LINQ is realization that LINQ deals with expressions, not statements. Therefore, you need to produce the whole list at once, and then either print it in a single `foreach` loop, or to use `string.Format` method to avoid loops altogether.

Here is how you prepare your data:

```
var rows = students
    .Join(
        studentScores
    ,   st => st.Id
    ,   sc => sc.StudentId
    ,   (st, sc) => new { Student = st, Score = sc }
    )
    .GroupBy(p => new { p.Student.Id, p.Score.Subject })
    .Select(g => new {
        Name = g.First().Student.Name
    ,   Subj = g.Key.Subject
    ,   Points = g.Sum(p => p.Score.Points)
    })
    .ToList();
```

Now you can go through this in a `foreach` loop, and print prepared results:

```
foreach (var r in rows) {
    Console.WriteLine($"Name: {r.Name} Subject: {r.Subject} Score: {r.Score}");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;


namespace ConsoleApplication27
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IEnumerable<Student> students = new List<Student> {
                new Student() {Id = 1, Name = "John", Age = 13},
                new Student() {Id = 2, Name = "Mary", Age = 12},
                new Student() {Id = 3, Name = "Anne", Age = 14}
            };
            IEnumerable<StudentScore> studentScores = new List<StudentScore> {
                new StudentScore() {StudentId = 1, Subject = "Maths", Points = 54},
                new StudentScore() {StudentId = 1, Subject = "Maths", Points = 32},
                new StudentScore() {StudentId = 1, Subject = "English", Points = 55},
                new StudentScore() {StudentId = 1, Subject = "English", Points = 54},

                new StudentScore() {StudentId = 2, Subject = "Maths", Points = 44},
                new StudentScore() {StudentId = 2, Subject = "Maths", Points = 37},
                new StudentScore() {StudentId = 2, Subject = "English", Points = 59},
                new StudentScore() {StudentId = 2, Subject = "English", Points = 64},

                new StudentScore() {StudentId = 3, Subject = "Maths", Points = 53},
                new StudentScore() {StudentId = 3, Subject = "Maths", Points = 72},
                new StudentScore() {StudentId = 3, Subject = "English", Points = 54},
                new StudentScore() {StudentId = 3, Subject = "English", Points = 59},
            };

            var groups = (from student in students
                          join studentScore in studentScores on student.Id equals studentScore.StudentId into st
                          select new { name = student.Name, scores = st })
                         .Select(x => x.scores.GroupBy(y => y.Subject).Select(z => new { name = x.name, subject = z.Key, totalPoints = z.Select(a => a.Points).Sum() }).ToList()).ToList();
            foreach(var group in groups)
            {
                foreach(var subject in group)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Student Name : '{0}', Subject : '{1}', Total Score : '{2}'", subject.name, subject.subject, subject.totalPoints);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public class Student
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
    public class StudentScore
    {
        public int StudentId { get; set; }
        public string Subject { get; set; }
        public int Points { get; set; }
    }
}
```